# styled-components não aceita ClassName no component pai, apenas nos components filhos

Tags: css, react, styled-components

Quando uso ClassName em um styled-components, ele não aplica os estilos configurados. Mas se uso o ClassName em umcomponent filho, então funciona. Em ambos os caso, o html gerado possui a class normalmente

no código abaixo, a pagina não redenriza a classe

```
import  styled  from  'styled-components'

const Div = styled.div`
font-size:45px;

.App{
  background-color:red
}`

function App() {
  return (
    <Div className="App">
      Ola Mundo
    </Div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Mas ainda assim, a classe é colocada no html, quando inspeciono a pagina:

```
<div id="root"><div class="sc-bdvvtL cJMkxy App">Ola Mundo</div></div>
```

Isso não acontece, se uso a ClassName e um component filho:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Div>
      <div className="App">
      Ola Mundo
      </div>
    </Div>
  );
}
```

pagina :

```
<div id="root"><div class="sc-bdvvtL cJMkxy"><div class="App">Ola Mundo</div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A biblioteca não aceita este tipo de sintaxe, visto que sua ideia principal seria CSS em JS. Classes nunca utilizadas manualmente, elas são inferidas automaticamente pela lib.

Neste caso, para estilizar o App, você teria que criar um componentes Styled para ele. Exemplo:

```
import  styled  from  'styled-components'

const AppStyled = styled.main`
  background-color: red;`

function App() {
  return (
    <AppStyled>
       <h1>Olá Mundo</h1>
    </AppStyled>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O erro está no seu CSS. Quando você declara `.App { /* ... */ }`, está se referindo a algo com a classe `App` dentro de `Div`. Use:

```
const Div = styled.div`
  font-size:45px;
  background-color:red`
```

Comment: Eu pretendia usar classes para poder mudar o estilo sem ter que usar variáveis no styled. Achei que seria mais fácil só trocar a classe do componente e ter o estilo estático.  Mas pelo que estou vendo, o styled-components desencoraja isso. Só queria entender exatamente o que estava acontecendo.

Comment: A ideia é que o estilo dos styled components seja totalmente isolado, e não "vaze" para o resto do seu HTML.

Answer (score 0):

A forma que está seu código, leva a entender que a classe `.app` está abaixo do componete Div. Quando na verdade a classe está no mesmo nível.

Pra editar qualquer coisa no mesmo nível do componente você pode usar `&` ficando dessa forma:

```
const Div = styled.div`
font-size:45px;

&.App{
  background-color:red
}`

&:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```